# PERCENTILE_DISC() in PostgreSQL as a window function

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

We are porting our system from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. In that we calculate Median Daily Turnovers for all companies on all dates for past 3 months. Below is the simplified query for the same

```
SELECT B.Company, B.Dt, B.Turnover,   (Select distinct
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Turnover)  OVER (PARTITION
BY B.Company, B.Dt) from Example_Tbl AS G  where G.Company = B.Company
and G.Dt <= B.Dt and  G.Dt > DateAdd(dd, -92, B.Dt)) as
Med_3m_Turnover FROM Example_Tbl B;
```

The problem is that PostgreSQL doesn't support the use of `percentile_disc()` as a window function. The error message is:

> ERROR: OVER is not supported for ordered-set aggregate percentile_disc

Is there any way I can implement the same functionality using something else in PostgreSQL.

edit: Here is example input data in Example_Tbl

```
Company  Dt   Turnover 
x        1    10 
x        2    45 
x        3    20 
y        1    300 
y        2    100  
y        3    200
```

And the ouptut should be as below. Please note, we are ignoring 3 Months right now and just have 3 rows per company

```
Company  Dt   Turnover   Med_3m_Turnover
x        1    10         10 
x        2    45         10 or 45 depending on percentile_desc
x        3    20         20 
y        1    300        300 
y        2    100        300 or 100 depending on percentile_desc
y        3    50         100
```

Comment: I must not be understanding your query completely, because I'm not sure how the `select distinct percentile_disc(...` part doesn't sometimes return more than one row, which would product an error.

Comment: @sstan. Without distinct clause, subquery will return multiple values and throw an error. Distinct is to stop exactly that.

Comment: Looks to me that you don't need `OVER` at all, as your subquery should only return one row, then just using `WITHIN GROUP` and no WINDOW FUNCTION.

Comment: @John: I get that, but couldn't the query still return more than one *distinct* value?  That's the part that's not clear to me.  The reason I say that is because the partition clause is by `B.Company, B.Dt`, yet the subquery has a filter condition on `G.Dt <= B.Dt`, which means that there may be multiple `B.Company, B.Dt` combinations, thus also making it possible to return multiple distinct percentile_disc values.  I know I must be wrong if your query works, but that's where I'm stuck trying to understand.

Comment: @sstan. Yes. The query works well for more than 7 million records in the table. So may be we do not encounter the data situation which will cause the error. I have updated the original question also to have example input data and example output data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Exact error is "ERROR:  OVER is not supported for ordered-set aggregate percentile_disc". "Within group is used before order by clause for the actual field to be sorted, in our case, the turnover.

Comment: @John: Actually, I just realized why the query never fails. It's because the `partition by` clause is using `B.Company, B.Dt` (which are constant values for that row) instead of `G.Company, G.Dt`. Not sure if this was intentional (I don't think so), but that's what prevents the error. Not sure you get the results you want though.

Comment: You are right @ MatheusOl. It was just there because without it SQL Server threw error. Thank you for your help....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `partition by` clause (`PARTITION
BY B.Company, B.Dt`) is using values from the outer query (alias `B`), not the subquery (alias `G`), which wasn't immediately obvious to me at first.  Because the values of `B.company` and `B.Dt` are constant for each execution of the subquery, then your partition clause is really no different than simply writing it like this:

```
... over (partition by 1)
```

You can test it in SQL Server if you want, but you'll find that the results are the same.  Now, I don't know if using `B.Company, B.Dt` was intentional or not, but in effect, it means that the `partition by` clause is not actually partitioning anything.

So, as a result, the good news for you is that to write the equivalent query in PostgreSQL, you simply need to omit the `OVER (PARTITION
BY B.Company, B.Dt)` clause entirely, and the behavior will be the same as in SQL Server.

Comment: Thank You @sstan. Yes, Query works just the same with "over (partition by 1)". I guess we must have put it there because SQL Server needs both WITHIN GROUP and OVER clause, though I don't know why. Without either of them, it gives errors. I will just remove partition reference in postgres. As I proceed with migration, I am sure I will encounter queries where I will need both. Will post another question for it when I reach there. Thanks again